# JQuery - Get the number of rows in a table body

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table that is defined as follows:

```
<table id="myTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Birth Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>03-11-1980</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to understand how to determine **how many rows are in the** `tbody` **portion of my table**, instead of the table in general. How do I use JQuery to determine how many rows are in the tbody portion of a table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("#myTable > tbody > tr").length
```

The [`a > b`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector selects all `b` elements that are *direct* children of an `a` element.  Therefore, this selector will not match rows in nested tables.

Comment: Wow! That's pretty cool. I had  no idea you could do that in JQuery. JQuery continues to impress me. Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried...

```
$("#myTable tbody tr").length
```

UPDATE: as mentioned in the comment - the above example doesn't account for nested tables.  If you want to cover that as well, you'd want to use the [parent/child selectors](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) instead.

```
$("#myTable > tbody > tr").length
```

Comment: `length` is not a function.  Also, this won't handle nested tables.

Comment: @SLaks - yeah, realized I had that wrong after I typed it.  updated my answer to fix the length issue.  Good call on the nexted tables - you get my vote on your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var amountOfRows = $("#myTable  tbody  tr").length;
alert(amountOfRows);
```

The variable amountOfRows will hold the number of rows. You can also use $("#myTable  tbody  tr").size
But that is a shortcut for .length

If used on nested tables see SLaks answer

Comment: This also won't handle nested tables.

Answer (score 1):

use this if you don't have a table id or just want to generalize tables

```
$('table.table').find('tbody').children().length;
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. It is helpful when you create table using jquery createElement() function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways you can do this, here are two of them

```
 var totalRows = ​$('tbody > tr > td').​​​​​length

 var totalRows2 = $('tbody').find('td').length
```

The var **totalRows** and **totalRows2** will have the number of `'td'` that are inside `tbody`